# How do I fix the homestead.rb path that is automatically used by vagrant?

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant

I ran the homestead make command successfully.
Afterward, I ran the vagrant up command in the vendor/bin folder, but I get the following error:

```
Vagrant failed to initialize at a very early stage:

There was an error loading a Vagrantfile. The file being loaded
and the error message are shown below. This is usually caused by
a syntax error.

Path: C:/xampp/htdocs/all-projects/project1/vendor/bin/Vagrantfile
Line number: 0
Message: LoadError: cannot load such file -- C:/xampp/htdocs/all-projects/project1/vendor/bin/vendor/laravel/homestead/scripts/homestead.rb
```

The path to homstead.rb is incorrect. Such a path does not exist and the homestead.rb file is in another folder for the project. How do I fix the homestead.rb path that is automatically used by vagrant?

P.S. the /laravel folder is present in the project directory.

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit your Vagrantfile. In there is a line that references homestead.rb. Mine looks like

```
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/scripts/homestead.rb')
```

Update this to be the correct path.